# How to access files over a remote desktop connection with OS

Tags: python, operating-system, rdp

I have a program which compares files to see which files I've updated and which files and folders are new.

I have a folder called `School` at home and at school with exactly the same contents in. My program works fine accessing and comparing files on my USB but I can't seem to find the correct path to access my files at school.

[EDIT]: I downloaded the `rdp` from my school website. To open my documents, I connect to `school.rdp`, type in my username and password then the window comes up.

[image]

This is the start of my program which finds the base folder

```
import os

# HOME, this works
print(os.path.exists("C:/School")) # True
print(os.path.exists("C:")) # True

# SCHOOL, I've tried all of these but none of them work
print(os.path.exists("N:/School")) # False
print(os.path.exists("N:/Documents")) # False
print(os.path.exists("N:")) # False
print(os.path.exists("N:/cha-sr-003/Students$/Intake2011/11FullerT/Documents/School")) # False
print(os.path.exists("//cha-sr-003/Students$/Intake2011/11FullerT/Documents/School")) # False
print(os.path.exists("cha-sr-003")) # False
```

Does anyone know a path which will allow me to access my folders on the remote desktop connection? If this isn't possible, is there any other way I can use to access them?

Thanks for your help

Comment: you mean you tried `\\cha-sr-003\Students$\Intake2011\11FullerT\Documents\School` from explorer and it worked?

Comment: Is this paths working from explorer?

Comment: Is it a Shared Folder called 'N:\' or not? 
And you want to look for any differences?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre, I don't know much about rdps. I downloaded the file `School.rdp` from explorer. To open my school documents, I open `school.rdp`, type in my username and password then the window comes up.

Comment: @13loodH4t, `N:/` is the path I used to access my documents when I'm at school, I don't have a folder called `N:/`, I think its just a system name or something

Comment: Try this please... print(os.path.exists("\\cha-sr-003\Students$\Intake2011\11FullerT\Documents\School"))

Comment: @13loodH4t, unfortunately no success

Comment: @13loodH4t use the raw prefix or that has zero chance to work: `print(os.path.exists(r"\\cha-sr-003\Students$\Intake2011\11Fu‌​llerT\Documents\Scho‌​ol"))`

Comment: Or this could help cause of UNC bugs in path.exists.. os.path.isabs(r"\\server")

Comment: @TomFuller you have to have admin rights on the remote machine or have a shared drive already defined by an admin to be able to use those UNC drive paths.

Comment: @13loodH4t OP uses `//` not `\\` so that's not the problem.

Comment: Please try something else: Press Windows button and [R] and type in "\\cha-sr-003\Students$\Intake2011\11F‌​u‌​llerT\Documents\S‌​cho‌​ol" and ok.. do you see your files?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre, so I can't access the files because I don't have the admin rights, do you think there is any way around it? Or its not possible?

Comment: can you access the files from explorer using UNC path?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre How do I find out my UNC path? I'm a bit of a noob at this sorry

Comment: put `\\cha-sr-003\Students$\Intake2011\11F‌​u‌​llerT\Documents\S‌​‌​cho‌​ol` in your explorer: does that work?

Comment: It says "can't reach this page", when I type it in the `rdp` it says "Accessing the resource `\\cha-sr-003\...` has been disallowed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to access my files because I didn't have access rights to the server.

To work around this problem I used two separate programs, each which creates a `.txt` file in my documents at home and at school. I then copied the `.txt` file from my school area to my home documents and used my program `compare.py` to compare both of the text files

Thanks to @Jean-François Fabre and @13loodH4t for your help